# Firebase Analytics custom events paramethers on Dashboard

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

I have a flutter app, and I'm implementing Firebase Analytics on it. I'm using logEvent(), and I saw that besides the event name we can pass a Map parameters. My question is whether these parameters need to have names that Firebase recognizes.
I tried to send an event from my app, but nothing appeared in the Firebase Dashboard.

```
     eventRegister(
            name: 'contacts',
            parameters: {'schedule': 'contacts_favorites'},
          );

//
    eventRegister({String name, Map<String, Object> parameters}) {
      analytics.logEvent(name: name, parameters: parameters);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For seeing parameters in firebase dashboard first check if the event is triggered in DebugView and then you need to define some custom definitions.

[image]

In new custom definition choose from your previously given parameters. Normally it takes several hours to get the parameters in event parameter.

[image]

The parameter will be shown in Dashboard as event parameter after 24 hours and you can download it as CSV/PDF

[image]