# Is there any way to store events parameter in google analytics in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to store the event parameters to google analytics but It is only displaying in realtime. I want to see all the parameters related to the event in dashboard. How did I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your google analytics go to Custom Dimension and set some Custom Dimensions. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69786358/11445727

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: How to see the parameter in the analytics dashboard? I've trying everything and I only see `(not set)` there in columns. Could you please tell the next steps after you include the parameter into Custom Dimensions? What do you do after that, please?

Comment: @KonstantinKozirev please follow the given link https://stackoverflow.com/a/69786358/11445727

Comment: turns out I used numerical for Custom Dimension, whereas it doesn't support numeric and Metric ought to be used instead. Yes and I saw that link, it's the same as in your answer.